# What facility does system crontab provide that user crontab for root cannot?

Tags: linux, cron

I will expand my question here:

What is the need of a system crontab when every user including root has its own crontab? The existence of the system crontab seems to duplicate functionality. Is the system crontab more of an artifact of the history of the cron system?

Comment: It is not a good idea to do stuff as root. You can really f*** stuff up Perhaps doing stuff with less power is a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System crontab is a great way for distro maintainers and app packagers to include cron jobs that don't pollute the user crontab space.

The system crontab files can specify a user to run as, so not everything in the system crontab has to run as root.

Non-login-users don't have crontabs, so the only place to put non-login-user tasks is in the system crontab.

Generally, you would put local/custom stuff in the root (or appropriate user) crontab, while prepackaged stuff that you don't directly maintain lives in the system crontab.

Really, it's just a matter of organization